# Same name column in pk and relation

Tags: java, spring-4, hibernate-5.x

Hollo, i have the class Rubro:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="ar.com.vgmsistemas.dto">
    <class name="Rubro" table="segmento">
        <composite-id class="PkRubro" name="id" unsaved-value="undefined">
            <key-property name="idNegocio" column="id_negocio"></key-property>
            <key-property name="idRubro" column="id_segmento"/>
        </composite-id>
        <property column="de_segmento" name="descripcion" type="string" />
        <many-to-one class="Negocio" name="negocio" column="id_negocio" insert="false" update="false" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem is the column id_negocio, because it is in both tables, in hibernate 3.3.1 its works correctly but in hibernate 5 with spring4 no.

The error is the next:

> MappingException: Error calling Value#setTypeUsingReflection:
>   containingClassName=[ar.com.vgmsistemas.dto.PkRubro],
>   propertyName=[idNegocio],
>   role=[ar.com.vgmsistemas.dto.Rubro.id.idNegocio] :
>   origin(com/ar/vgmsistemas/dto/mapping/Rubro.hbm.xml)

From already thank you very much.
Regards.

Comment: Please describe the problem a bit more clear. Right now it's not clear what you mean with "works correctly" or what the problem with hibernate-5 axtually is. Add what you see, and what you expect to see.

Comment: Hi, i edited the content. Regards.